# Objective-c - How to store objects in database SQLite

Tags: sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm curious to learn more about storing objects.

If I have an app that manage an office database where I have model object like Department, Employee, Task. How can I store them in the database?

Should I create a table for each model and store the primitive instance values like name, id, surname ? Or should I store the object itself?

Which is the right approach??

To better understand:
How an app like whatsapp or kik (both chat/messaging application) store their data in their server? Do they use coredata or databases? Do they save primitive values or objects?

Comment: Have you thought about using Core Data? Have a look at this tutorial to help you get started. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: THank you.....i'm gonna read the tutorial but right now what i need to know is how to save objects in a database with SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

A popular pratice is to use Core Data to store locally and use Web API to sync with server.

For example, we're developing an app using Core Data to map objects to SQLite, handled by API apple provided, and using RestKit, an third-party library to map objects to requests understandable to server API, thus, you can see your data published on server

Not quite sure it's what your're asking for, this pratice is straightforward for manipulating complicated objects, compared to using SQL directly.